# CSS fixing an element besides another

Tags: html, css, position

just a simple question i am stuck with. i am playing around with some html and css, i would like to create a page with content box in the centre of the page and two images of arrows on either side of the content box. now thats not hard at all, the issue is i am using position: absolute; so if i change the window size the elements go nuts..

my html:

```
<div id= "left_side">
  <a href=""><img id="leftArrow" src="images/lefta.png"/></a>
</div>

<div id="right_side">
  <a href=""><img id="rightArrow" src="images/righta.png"/></a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>something</p>
  <p>more something</p>
</div>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
#left_side {
  border: black solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 65px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  }

#right_side {
  border: black solid 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 65px 210px 0px 0px ;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  }

#content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 15px 320px 15px 320px;
  padding: 30px;
  border:5px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  }
```

what can i change so that the side images/buttons are relative to the content box at all times no matter what the screen size. i was thinking of nesting them in a bigger box but is that the best practice or am i going off on the wrong foot all together. sorry for the simple question, i am new to this and positioning always kills me.

thanks in advance

Comment: please host this on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally use two wrapper divs to center anything inside them (no absolute style). CSS:

```
.couter
{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.cinner
{
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

And use like:

```
<div class="couter">
    <div class="cinner">
        <div id= "left_side">
          <a href=""><img id="leftArrow" src="images/lefta.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="right_side">
          <a href=""><img id="rightArrow" src="images/righta.png"/></a>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
          <p>something</p>
          <p>more something</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that code is a lot more DRY then mine! ill take a swing at that direction

Answer (score 1):

I have created a jsfiddle for you with a possible solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/simonweston/MuTEn/

HTML:

```
<div id= "left_side">
LEFT
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>something</p>
  <p>more something</p>
</div>
<div id="right_side">
  RIGHT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left_side {
  border: black solid 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  }

#right_side {
  border: black solid 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  }

#content {
  background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
  border:5px;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  }
```

Comment: wow thank man, you sir are a wizard indeed. so making them all float i tried floating the right and left sides but that just went nuts as well. thanks

Comment: note that, whole content (all 3 divs) are not center aligned (as those are float elements).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content to expand when the page expands, this is how you could do that:

http://jsfiddle.net/VKBTy/

Also, I would use a container box with position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

The layout which you need can be brought in a very simpler way..

I have modified your css as

```
#left_side {float:left;width:100px;padding:10px;}
#right_side {float:left;width:100px;padding:10px;}
#content {width:500px;float:left;background:blue;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

and your HTML as

```
<div id= "left_side">
  <a href=""><img id="leftArrow" src="images/lefta.png"/></a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>something</p>
  <p>more something</p>
</div>

<div id="right_side">
  <a href=""><img id="rightArrow" src="images/righta.png"/></a>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Please use this code to check whether you got your requirement right..