# 100% child divs are on different rows

Tags: css

I'm not sure why the divs are not on the same line:

http://jsfiddle.net/LXHfy/

How can I achieve this? If I use 40% the 2 child divs align properly.

I'm not asking for a float solution. I just want to know why this is not working.

Comment: instead of using display:inline-block, try float:left to both child and parent?

Comment: I wish to center the divs, so float is out of the question.

Comment: to center floated divs see the first answer of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696978/css-fixing-an-element-besides-another/9697173#9697173

Answer (score 2):

simple:

- your parent div is 100px
- children are inline-block (side-by-side)
- children are 50% (50px)

however, when using inline-block, the newline/whitespace will introduce a "gap" between the elements, thus 50px+50px+"gap" = greater than parent's width, forcing the child to wrap below the other instead of sitting beside.

to avoid that gap, don't put whitespace:

```
<parent>
    <child>foo</child><child>bar</child>
                     ^^^--no gap, whitespace or newline between
```

usually, i do it like this on list items so that the closing and opening has no whitespace:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       item
   </li><li> //close and open immediately, no gaps
       item
   </li><li>
       item
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: updated the answer. it's ok to have newline *inside* the child, just not between each other.

Comment: @danip, you can separate with comments: `...</div><!-- NEWLINE
  --><div>..` - but this is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use floating divs. Add:

```
float: left;
```

And to stop floating add in the end of row empty div with property:

```
clear:both;
```

Answer (score 0):

**display:inline-block** always take some spacing from the right. So, we can remove with `font-size:0`, `word-spacing:1em`, `letter-spacing:1em` to there parent.Write like this:

```
.parent {font-size:0;}
.child {font-size:15px}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LXHfy/6/